# Why am I getting "RuntimeError: yield was used instead of yield from for generator in task Task" while trying to use asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio

f = open('filename.txt', 'w')

@asyncio.coroutine
def fun(i):
    print(i)
    f.write(i)
    # f.flush()

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.as_completed([fun(i) for i in range(3)]))
    f.close()

main()
```

I'm trying to use python3's new library `asyncio` .but I'm getting this error dont know why. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specific error you're hitting is because you're trying to pass the return value of `asyncio.as_completed` to `run_until_complete`. `run_until_complete` expects a `Future` or `Task`, but `as_completed` returns an iterator. Replace it with `asyncio.wait`, which returns a `Future`, and the program will run fine.

**Edit:**

Just for reference, here's an alternative implementation that uses `as_completed`:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def fun(i):
    # async stuff here
    print(i)
    return i

@asyncio.coroutine
def run():
    with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
        for fut in asyncio.as_completed([fun(i) for i in range(3)]):
           i = yield from fut
           f.write(str(i))

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run())


main()
```

Comment: but I want my result as soon as it is available ..thats why I used `as_completed` ,..in this program range(3) is a sample. actually its length is in millions

Comment: @michael You're already writing the  value of `i` inside the coroutine, aren't you? I think maybe your real intentions are getting lost here because the sample code is missing too much information. Does the real `fun` contain calls to `yield from`? Is the real `i` something calculated inside of `fun`?

Comment: @michael You can just use `asyncio.wait` here. Each instance of `fun` is writing `i` itself, so it's already guaranteed that `i` will be written as soon as `fun` is done. Furthermore, the writes are guaranteed to be synchronized properly; since the file writes are not actually asynchronous operations, only one coroutine will be able to do the write at a time.

Comment: @michael You could refactor this so that you added a coroutine that ran something like `for fut in asyncio.as_completed(..): f.write(yield from fut)`, but since you're already doing it in the coroutine itself, there's no need. Though I guess it's arguably more readable to use `as_completed`.

Comment: If you're talking about your original code, just use `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([fun(i) for i in range(3)]))` instead of `loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.as_completed([fun(i) for i in range(3)]))`.